# Has Mysql Query Executed - Confirm query has executed correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently written a script that writes to a database every ten minutes. The aim of the script is to update the record if a record for that user exists else it inserts a record for that user.

The database has three important fields, `id` `username` `ip`.

As the IP changes the script will update the IP field for that user or add a record for the user with the new IP and on the next run update the IP rather than add a record.

I am trying to find out the best way to know if the record exists so that I can update rather than insert.

I was previously using `$f->rowCount()` after the update statement ie

```
if($f->rowCount() > 0){ continue; }else{ the insert statement}
```

So if the affected rows were greater than 0 I know the record exists. However, if the IP had not changed, effectively no update ever took place and the `$f->rowCount()` would be equal to `0`.

Now I am simply select all records and store them in an array, check if the username is `in_array` if so do an update, else do an insert. Is there a better or quicker way to ensure whether a record exists, without having to do a select?

My question is really to see if something similar to `$f->rowCount()` exists as I only discovered this the other day. Many thanks

Comment: for me it's very unclear what you are doing. specially "As the IP changes the script will update the IP field for that user or add a record for the user with the new IP and on the next run update the IP rather than add a record." - when will it update the record, when will it insert a new one? please provide more of your code since i don't understand the logic you wanna use.

Comment: @northkildonan What I think OP is implying, is that if the combo of  username and IP exists then nothing should happen (an update here is thus redundant). Unclear though why he's going on user name instead of user id and IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly make those three columns into a unique key. This would allow you to use the
`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` query expression:

```
INSERT INTO `users`
([other fields], `username`, `ip`)
VALUES ([values for other fields], [user name], [IP address]) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE [other fields]=[other values], `username`=[user name], `ip`=[IP address]
```

Comment: this is looking good. I did not know about `ON DUPLICATE KEY` when an `INSERT` fails due to a duplicate key.

Answer (score 1):

silkfire's answer is looking very promising. but if you don't wanna change the unique keys in your table, why not change the query for your `rowCount()`?
for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` 
WHERE `ip` = [IP address]
AND 'username' = [user name]
```

looks like you are using PDO; so with `$f->fetchColumn()` on this statement you'll know if this exact combination already exists. you will also know if it exists more than once.